# Enable clicking on the Green circles in Eclipse to jump to code

Tags: eclipse, ide

How can I enable clicking on this bubble (or perhaps the name) to instantly jump to the underlined place in code? By pressing f2 and clicking on a small box, the same effect can be achieved, but I remember being able to work far faster doing this on one of my old projects.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hold Ctrl and hover over the method name. You can then choose to jump to the declaration or super implementation.

Comment: Helpful, but not quite as easy because it involves the keyboard. If there's no way to renable the feature, I'll just accept this answer.